# How to monitor external service in prometheus-operator

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I am trying to monitor external service (which is exporter of cassandra metrics) in prometheus-operator. I installed prometheus-operator using helm 2.11.0. I installed it using this yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system
```

and these commands on my kubernetes cluster:

```
kubectl create -f rbac-config.yml
helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 200
helm install stable/prometheus-operator --name prometheus-operator --namespace monitoring
```

Next, basing on article:
[how monitor to an external service](https://devops.college/prometheus-operator-how-to-monitor-an-external-service-3cb6ac8d5acb)

I tried to do steps described in it. As suggested I created Endpoints, Service and ServiceMonitor with label for existing Prometheus. Here are my yaml files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: cassandra-metrics80
  labels:
    app: cassandra-metrics80
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.150.1.80
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 7070
    protocol: TCP
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cassandra-metrics80
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: cassandra-metrics80
    release: prometheus-operator
spec:
  externalName: 10.150.1.80
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 7070
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7070
  type: ExternalName
```

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: cassandra-metrics80
  labels:
    app: cassandra-metrics80
    release: prometheus-operator
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra-metrics80
      release: prometheus-operator
    namespaceSelector:
      matchNames:
      - monitoring
  endpoints:
  - port: web
    interval: 10s
    honorLabels: true
```

And in prometheus service discovery page I can see:
[image: Service Discovery]

That this service is not active and all labels are dropped.
I did a numerous things trying to fix this, like setting targetLabels. Trying to relabel the once that are discovered, as
described here: [prometheus relabeling](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/1166#issuecomment-447404996) 
But unfortunately nothing works. What could be the issue or how can I investigate it better?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found out that service should be in the same namespace as service monitor and endpoint, after that prometheus started to see some metrics from cassandra.

Comment: Also, Endpoint and Service must have the same name.

Comment: That is not true. ServiceMonitor can be in a different Namespace than Service and Endpoints as long as you have appropriate Role and RoleBinding (if you use RBAC).

Comment: Example Role and RoleBinding manifest: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/tree/main/example/additional-scrape-configs

Answer (score 2):

When using the [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) helm chart, it can be done as follows

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
    - job_name: external
      metrics_path: /metrics
      static_configs:
        - targets:
          - <IP>:<PORT>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be strict only "Endpoints" and "Service" should be in the same namespace.
Additionally "Endpoints" and "Service" should have the same name as Lucas mentioned it before.

ServiceMonitor can be placed anywhere, it finds and scrapes SVC/Endpoint inside defined namespaces (namespaceSelector->matchNames) and matching all labels (selector->matchLabels):

```yaml
    spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra-metrics80
      release: prometheus-operator
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - my-namespace
```

Furthermore now there is much more easier method to define additional scraping:
https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md
The only drawback for the second one is that it requires pod restart after the change. Configuration based on Endpoint/Service/ServiceMonitor seem to be discovered and applied automatically.

Comment: Thank you for making that precise, unfortunatelly I have no option to check if that is correct. Best Regards.

Comment: That is true. ServiceMonitor can be in a different Namespace than Service and Endpoints as long as you have appropriate Role and RoleBinding (if you use RBAC).

Answer (score 0):

I think your use case is better covered by the `Probe` resource.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Probe
metadata:
  name: cassandra-metrics80
  labels:
    app: cassandra-metrics80
    release: prometheus-operator
spec:
  jobName: cassandra-metrics80
  interval: 10s
  scrapeTimeout: 5s
  prober:
    url: 10.150.1.80:7070
    path: /metrics
    scheme: http
  targets:
    staticConfig:
      static:
      - 10.150.1.80:7070
```

It should be functionally equivalent to pat-s answer, but instead of hardcoding it in the prometheus configuration file you can flexibly handle it like you would with a `ServiceMonitor` resource.